# .htaccess redirect to new domain with new page name

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

Does anyone know how (or if) I can do an `.htaccess` redirect if both the domain and page name have changed?

I can get `olddomain.com/page/` to redirect to `newdomain.com/page/` (same page name), but not `olddomain.com/page/` to `newdomain.com/new-page/`.

Is the only way to do two redirects: `olddomain.com/page/` to `newdomain.com/page/` and then another from `newdomain.com/page/` to `newdomain.com/new-page/`?

Comment: You should be able to do this in a single redirect in exactly the same way!? There should be nothing unusual about this. Maybe you have some kind of conflict in your existing rules? Please include what you have tried and possibly include the contents of your entire `.htaccess` file - the order of directives matters and there may be conflicts?

Comment: Please tell us more about your setup.  Are you serving the domains out of separate directories?   What are the rules that you have tried that don't work?  Please edit your question and add information so it can be re-opened.